# Flex Mobile Application: StageWebView scaleX or scaleY

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

```
protected function loadWeb():void
        {   
            var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();              
            webView.stage = this.stage; 
            webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,(navigator.actionBar.height), (systemManager.screen.width),
                (systemManager.screen.height- navigator.actionBar.height-FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.tabbedNavigator.tabBar.height));
            webView.loadURL("http://www.google.com.tr");

        }
```

I used StageWebView component to load web page,www.google.com.tr, into stage with this code. Everything is OK. But I want to use this webView with different scale for iphone and ipad. Is there any way to scale StageWebView component?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the scaleMode of the stage?

```
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

protected function loadWeb():void
{   
    var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView(); 
    this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
    webView.stage = this.stage; 
    webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,(navigator.actionBar.height), (systemManager.screen.width),
        (systemManager.screen.height- navigator.actionBar.height-FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.tabbedNavigator.tabBar.height));
    webView.loadURL("http://www.google.com.tr");

}
```